# Node.js:Route precedence and ordering (sails.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

In my `sails.js` application i have two routes like this:

```
    '/': {controller:'HomeController',action:'home'},

   'GET /:category/:subcategory/:keyword':{controller:'SearchController',action:'index'
```

When I run the default route (`/`) it will always execute this route
`GET /:category/:subcategory/:keyword` .

Why is this happening??

The order of routes in route file is

1) `/`

2) `GET /:category/:subcategory/:keyword`

Comment: `GET /:category/:subcategory/:keyword` is a bit like saying `GET /*/*/*` so it likely matching your `/`.. If you call next on none-matching routes in your `GET /:category...`, you can reverse the order so it gets checked first.

Comment: so i need to place  `GET /:category/:subcategory/:keyword` route in first place??

Comment: Actually, no.. I don't think that makes sense.. erm.. I've not really used sails.js.. but I've a feeling you might want  `GET /` in the first route.

Comment: now `GET /` is first in route

Comment: Does it give you the homepage, but also access the SearchController route? If so, I'd bet that some resource on your homepage accidentally matches that route. For example, if you have an image with `src="/images/icons/smiley.png"`, that would match your `/:category/:subcategory/:keyword` route. Similar for scripts and other resources.

Comment: Yes it's matches the assets routes

Comment: So how can I avoid it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, your very general route `/:category/:subcategory/:keyword` is being hit because it must match asset urls on your homepage. This route will match any three-part path, ex:

- `/images/icons/smiley.png`
- `/scripts/thirdparty/jquery.min.js`

Etc!

There would be two approaches to fix this. One would be making your `SearchController` urls more specific. Maybe `/search/:category/:subcategory/:keyword` would be a good idea? This is the simplest and should clear up any conflicts with your assets right away.

---

But if you really need catch-all routes that can interfere with other specific routes, then the solution is to catch the specific routes first. For example, in `routes.js`:

```
'GET /images/*': 'RouteController.showAsset',
'GET /scripts/*': 'RouteController.showAsset',
'GET /styles/*': 'RouteController.showAsset',
//...
'GET /:category/:subcategory/:keyword': 'SearchController.index',
```

Then create a controller `RouteController` with the method:

```
showAsset: function(req, res) {
    var pathToAsset = require('path').resolve('.tmp/public', req.path);
    // ex should be '.tmp/public/images/icons/smiley.png'
    return res.sendfile(pathToAsset);
},
```

You may need to add something in to check for file existence first, but this is the idea.

I found this approach worthwhile when I wanted a `/:userName` route that would not conflict with all of my `/contact`, `/about`, `/robots.txt`, `/favicon.ico`, etc. However, it takes work to maintain, so if you think the first approach can work for you, I would use that.

Comment: Let me try your answer